# AngularJS Controller executed before app.run

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am relatively new to Ionic and AngularJS.
In an Ionic app I have written a database service. This service has a init function which is called inside my

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
...
})
```

in

```
.run()
```

My problem is, that the default controller also uses my service and is called before the service is initialized. How can I let the controller wait for the service is initialized?

I tried to define a varable `var promise = $q.defer();` and resolve it inside the init function and made it accessible via `this.promise = promise.promise;`
Then I put this inside my .state for this controller

```
resolve: {
    initialized:  dbService.promise
}
```

But this didn't work.

How can I fix this?